# normalization in theano for any image?

Tags: python, theano

I write below code but that is very slow. And, of course, does not work correct!

**I have what I do?**

```
for i in range(image_shape[0]):
    for j in range(filter_shape[0]):
        pmin = self.pooled_out[i][j].min()
        pmax = self.pooled_out[i][j].max()
        self.pooled_out = T.set_subtensor(T.set_subtensor(self.pooled_out[i], self.pooled_out[i])[j],self.pooled_out[i][j] - pmin)
        self.pooled_out = T.set_subtensor(T.set_subtensor(self.pooled_out[i], self.pooled_out[i])[j],self.pooled_out[i][j] / pmax)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First that section of your code do nothing. Just remove this line

```
T.set_subtensor(self.pooled_out[i], self.pooled_out[i])
```

Without full code, I can't test my solution, but I think this would do what you want:

```
pmin = self.pooled_out.min(axis=[2,3], keepdims=True)
pmax = self.pooled_out.max(axis=[2,3], keepdims=True)
normalized_pooled_out = (self.pooled_out - pmin)/pmax
```

Then normalized_pooled_out contain the symbolic variable that have the value I think you want.